# RewriteRule htaccess friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I'm trying to make firendly urls.
My site url is:

> domain.pl/index.php?str=prod_big&idk=869&kat=

My .htaccess code is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.pl$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?str=$1&idk=$2&kat= [L]
```

But after visiting:

> http://domain.pl/prod_big/869.html

nothing happens. What should i do more ?

Comment: `RewriteEngine On` should be on top of the all `RewriteRules`. And what do you mean by _nothing happens_?

Comment: after entering old url it doesn't redirect to new one